# Passiv des Modalverbes in Subjektivbedeutung

Tags: modal-verb, passive, tense

Ich habe den folgenden Satz selber geschrieben, indem ich mich nur auf mein Bauchgefühl verlassen habe. Ich konnte die Regel, die beschreibt, wie man in Vergangenheit einen Passiv des Modalverbes in Subjektivbedeutung bildet, nicht finden.

Der Satz lautet:

> “Berichten zufolge sollen die vegetarischen Burger auf demselben Grill **gebraten worden** wie die, die aus dem echten Fleisch zubereitet wurden.“

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob die Form, die fettgedruckt ist, auch die richtige ist.

Comment: Da Fragen nach Korrektheit von Sätzen bei strenger Auslegung der Regeln off-topic sind, hier anstelle einer Antwort ein Hinweis: Ein Modalverb wie *sollen* wird zusammen mit einem Infinitiv verwendet. Dieser fehlt hier.

Comment: Soll recht sein. Man kann auch das "sollen" gleich ersetzen, mehrere Versionen denkbar. Sie wurden gebraten ... oder sie sind gebraten worden.

Comment: @RHa Wie kommt man auf die Idee, Fragen nach der Korrektheit könnten off-topic sein?

Comment: Die Gründe für eine Schließung als off-topic schließen *Proofreading* ein.

Comment: @RHa Nach einem konkreten Aspekt eines einzelnen Satzes zu fragen ist sicherlich kein proofreading. Außerdem hat doch niemand für die Schließung votiert? Da kann man ruhigen Gewissens antworten.

Comment: @RHa wenn ich mich richtig erinnere waren die Voraussetzungen für diese Art von Fragen das Vorweisen eigener Recherche und die Beschränkung auf einen einzelnen Satzteil. Streng genommen ist beides hier der Fall und eine Antwort ist angebracht.

Comment: Also, die Frage könnte auch lauten, wie man Passiv in Vergangenheit mit den Sätzen, die subjektive-Bedeutung der Modalverben enthalten, bildet. Der obere Satz ist nur ein Beispiel, bei dem ich in Schwierigkeiten geraten bin.

Comment: @hajef: Und es ist auch relevant, ob die allgemeine Struktur der Frage herausgearbeitet wird oder ob man sich nur für die Korrektur eines konkretes Satzes interessiert, ohne ihn exemplarisch für eine Klasse von Fällen zu verstehen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die korrekte Form für eine Passivform in der Vergangenheit (Perfekt) ist `soll [...] gebraten worden sein`.

Ich wäre allerdings auch nicht auf die Regel gekommen, also danke an @RHa aus den Komentaren. "Sollen" als Modalverb benötigt in der Regel ein infinites Hauptverb (außer es darf in [Ausnahmefällen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalverb#Besonderheiten_in_der_Syntax_der_deutschen_Modalverben) weggelassen oder ersetzt werden).

Im Präsens würde der Satz übrigens heißen `soll [...] gebraten werden`.

Comment: Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, aber "gebraten sein" würde ja heißen, dass die Burger schon gebraten sind. Alle Burger. Ich verstehe es als einen allgemeinen Zustand, dass Burger gebraten werden.

Comment: Bin mir auch unsicher ob "soll gebraten sein" der Präsens ist ...

Comment: @a_donda Natürlich ist "soll gebraten sein" Päsens, genauer gesagt Zustandspassiv.

Answer (score 4):

Modalverben im Regelfall mit Infinitiv. Infinitive im Deutschen:

1. Infinitiv Präsens: *vergessen*
2. Infinitiv Perfekt: *vergessen haben*
3. Infinitiv Präsens Passiv: *vergessen werden*
4. Infinitiv Perfekt Passiv: *vergessen worden sein*
5. Infinitiv Präsens Zustandspassiv: *vergessen sein*
6. Infinitiv Perfekt Zustandspassiv: *vergessen gewesen sein*
7. Infinitiv Perfekt 2 (Superperfekt): *vergessen gehabt haben*

Beispiele:

1. Er will die ganze Geschichte vergessen.
2. Sie muss den Termin vergessen haben.
3. Das darf auf keinen Fall vergessen werden.
4. Da liegt ein Schlüssel, der muss vergessen worden sein.
5. In zwei, drei Jahren wird das alles sicher vergessen sein. (halbmodales 'wird')
6. ?Das kann nicht "vergessen" gewesen sein, er muss es absichtlich getan haben.
7. Er muss den Schlüssel vergessen gehabt haben - sonst wäre er doch nicht noch einmal zurückgefahren!